# returning back to main activity from SettingActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, preferenceactivity

I got SettingActivity from AndroidStudio Gallery, which uses ActionBar. Everything is fine when I click back button from ActionBar inside SettingsActivity. But when I want to return to main activity using this button in ActionBar nothing happens.

My SettingsActivity uses headers for preferences, so I thought I can check whether I am "inside" any of these headers, and if answer is none then I am in main setting screen and I can call main activity using startActivity(this,MainActivity.class). But problem is I cann't determine whether I am in start screen or in some header. Of course if there are more easy ways to do it I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1):

to make action bar back press return back , you have to do it in menu item selected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
    }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem));        
}
```

Comment: it helped, but I have question, how it understands that it must start that intent? I mean it I am inside some preference header and click back, does it go inside case android.R.id.home? Or it works only when i am going back from settings initial screen and in other cases there are other itemids?